# Are there any sites for camper van hire in Greece?

Tags: car-rentals, greece, campers

Many countries in southern Europe have rental services for small camping vans such as VW Transporters. In Portugal and Spain for example many private people rent out camping vans on platforms like Airbnb. I couldn't find anything comparable for Greece.

Is there a platform where such things could be found, either private or commercial?

Comment: Alternative to what ?

Comment: I meant alternative to what e.g. Airbnb offers in other places. I changed the sentence

Answer (score 5):

I found lots of pages for camping van rentals for Greece such as

- [website 1](http://www.caravan-web.gr/selida/enoikiaseis-aytokinoymenon) (there is no english website but I found the e-mail of this company - info@caravan-web.gr
- [website 2](http://www.motorhomes.gr/en/vehicles.html) This has an english page.

There are plenty more websites if you google 'ενοικίαση τροχόσπιτου'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, the second one I already found myself. I was looking for smaller vans though, not full-sized caravans. I guess thought that you answer will be helpful for many who accidentally come across this question

Comment: @sheß You could send an e-mail to these companies. Maybe they have something smaller.

Comment: then again there is this http://europeanvans.gr/en/european-vans-rent-a-van-daily-van-rental/

Comment: Thanks, i wrote to a few of those last week. They all responded that they don't. For the last one I can't see any camping-vans there. But I'll write them too. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @sheß one last try! :::: http://www.rentaldeals.gr/model/rent-a-car-vw-transporter